# in .NET when you pass a class instance/interface as a parameter do you pass one object or the full vtable

Tags: .net, oop, clr, cil, virtual-functions

If you are passing an interface or an instance of a class as a parameter, are we  passing many objects or the full vtable, because once you call a method on the instance it need to recurse the vtable and call the appropriate one right?
How does this work?

Answer (score 6):

You're passing a reference (by value). The exact representation of a reference is implementation-specific, but in most cases it will be a pointer :)

See http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html for more details.

(I'm on a phone at the moment - if someone could reformat the link that would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You're ultimately passing a pointer to the object, which contains a pointer to the vtable. Well, basically.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a whole series of posts on what exactly happens when you call a method in IL. The series starts at http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/11/01/95464.aspx

In short, a native-sized pointer is pushed onto the stack, that points into the heap at the start of the object instance (the sync block index, followed by the type pointer, followed by the instance's field values). The CLR gets to the vtable through the type pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation detail, so I think you shouldn't rely on that !:)

btw, there's no such thing as "passing an interface in parameter". You always pass an object reference which can implement none, one or several interfaces.

Comment: Watch out for some post on Raymond Chen's blog in a few years, because he'll write about some old application that did rely on that!

Comment: @OregonGhost :ahah, very true !